# Null parameter using $http.post , AngularJS

Tags: c#, json, angularjs

I'm getting a null parameter for "id".
If I don't JSON.Stringify the id I get the JSON primitive error.

```
$scope.deleteSite = function (id) {
    $http.post(ROOT + 'SiteList/Delete/', JSON.stringify(id)) //null id
    //$http.post(ROOT + 'SiteList/Delete/', id) //Invalid JSON primitive: 5f6d794f-bf13-4480-9afd-3b10d7b6ae32.
        .success(function (result) {
            // log to console?
        }).
        error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            // log to console?
        });
```

Here is my siteList delete controller.

```
public JsonResult Delete(String id)
    {
        try
        {
            var convertedID = new Guid(id);
            _siteService.Delete(convertedID); 
            return Json("OK", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return Json("Error" + e.Message);
        }

    }
```

Comment: I fiddled around with an MVC project and the answer is below for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A note, you can use `angular.toJson` as well. Which I think could be better - but you can look at the implementation differences if you wish.

Is this Web Api?

**Web Api:**

You have to configure the params, because delete works this way.

```
$scope.deleteSite = function (id) {
  $http.delete(ROOT + 'SiteList', { params: { id: id }}) 
    .success(function (result) {
      // log to console?
    }).
    error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
      // log to console?
    });
}
```

Controller Action, `[FromUri]` is needed because you configure the params:

```
public JsonResult Delete([FromUri] Guid id)
{
  try
  {
    _siteService.Delete(id); 
    return Json("OK", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    return Json("Error" + e.Message);
  }

}
```

Unconfigured params means:

```
$scope.deleteSite = function (id) {
  $http.delete(ROOT + 'SiteList/' + id ) 
    .success(function (result) {
      // log to console?
    }).
    error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
      // log to console?
    });
}
```

Controller Action:

```
public JsonResult Delete(Guid id)
{
  try
  {
    _siteService.Delete(id); 
    return Json("OK", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    return Json("Error" + e.Message);
  }

}
```

If this isn't Web Api, then you just need to make an object out of the request data.

**MVC**:

```
$scope.deleteSite = function (id) {
  $http.post(ROOT + 'SiteList/Delete/', { id: id})
    .success(function (result) {
      // log to console?
    }).
    error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
      // log to console?
    });
}
```

Controller Action:

```
public JsonResult Delete(Guid id)
{
  try
  {
    _siteService.Delete(id); 
    return Json("OK", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    return Json("Error" + e.Message);
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Callum, I'm using MVC so I just needed to make an object from the data.

Comment: @EricColgan Okay, cool. Just remember to state all the technologies you are using because it makes it easier to answer :P